# Python iterating over complex dict

Tags: python

I have some problems with correct iteration over complex dict.
The dictionary is:

```
links = {1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)}
```

The iterating code is:

```
link_params = []

for nodea, nodeb in links.iteritems():
    link = {}
    for i in nodeb:
        link.update({
            "selementid1": nodea,
            "selementid2": i,
        })
        link_params.append(link)
```

I get :

```
[{'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 10}]
```

But I want to get:

```
[{'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 2},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 3},
 {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 4}, etc.]
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Because you iterate and assign all the values in the links dictionary to your key "selementid2", the last value which is 10 is what is stored and printed. What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you expecting a list of dicts as output? if so

```
links = {1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)} 
link_params = []
for nodea, nodeb in links.iteritems():
  for i in nodeb:
      link_params.append({
           "selementid1": nodea,
           "selementid2": i,
           })
print link_params  #[{'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 2}, {'selementid1': 1, 'selementid2': 3},....
```

or

using list comprehension

```
links = {1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)} 
link_params = [{"selementid1": nodea,"selementid2": i} for nodea, nodeb in links.iteritems() for i in nodeb]
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: According to the documentation the author linked, this is precisely what the author was hoping their algorithm would do. Perhaps an explanation for how this differs from the author's method is due.

Comment: Yep, I've attempted to explain why the algorithm doesn't work as the author expects it to work.

Comment: @HuuNguyen, didn't see documentation. Was it removed?

Comment: Yeah it was. Found the link in my history. [Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/map/create) it is.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you've declared a dictionary outside your inner for loop.

> link = {}

You are mutating it with every inner for loop run.

> link.update({
>                  "selementid1": nodea,
>                  "selementid2": i,
>                  })

Also you're appending it to link_params as many times as the inner for loop runs.

> link_params.append(link)

You actually need something like this:

> links = {1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)}
>
> link_params = []
>
> for nodea, nodeb in links.iteritems():
>
> ```
>   for i in nodeb:
>
>        link_params.append({"selementid1": nodea,
>            "selementid2": i})
> ```
>
> print link_params